# Ionic v3 pass value to another page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I need your help. I want to pass data written by user in a text field to another page. My goal is to use the data passed as variable in the second page to print in console.log.

The problem is that I can see in console.log the right value (what I write in text field) and an "undefined" at the same line of the same page.

In my first page.ts I have

```
export class LoginPage {

public nomeUtente: string;


constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,

) {

}

nomeScelto() {
  let nomeUtente = this.nomeUtente;
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {data: nomeUtente});
    return {
      data :nomeUtente
    }
}
```

and in the corresponding html

```
    <ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Codice Matrimonio</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci qui il codice"
        [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && blur"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Nome</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nomeUtente" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Accedi!
    </button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

So, now I have this in my HomePage

```
    export class HomePage {

  nomeUtente: any;

constructor(
  private camera: Camera,
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public zone: NgZone,
  public navParams: NavParams,

) {
  this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;

  let nomeUtente = navParams.get('data');

  console.log(nomeUtente);
  }
```

and in console.log I see

exactlyWhatIWriteInNomeUtente     home.ts:33

undefined                         home.ts:33

Do you have any suggest?

Comment: Try to use `navParams.data` and if you still get undefined, please console the navParams and you can see object and then you can get easily your data value if it is there.

Comment: Ok if I use navParams.data or console.log(navParams.data) I can see what I write in the input text and also an empty { }. There is a way to show only the first log and not the empty one?

Comment: you have console only `navParams.data`. then why it is printing two logs ? Please check that you don't have console.log more than one in the file.

Comment: I've checked over and over again.. in console I can see two log refering at the same line of code, one is the right one and the other is undefined or { } depends how I code.

Comment: please try this `this.navParams.data` and then let me know

Comment: console.log(this.navParams.data);
I used this and I've always this in console:
{data: "provanomeutente"} home.ts:33 (this one is correct)
{ } home.ts:33 (this is what I see now, before was "undefined")

Comment: Some of you have any ideas? I'm still fighting to make it work..

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below ([source](https://ionicacademy.com/pass-data-angular-router-ionic-4/)):

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  user = {
    name: 'Simon Grimm',
    website: 'www.ionicacademy.com',
    address: {
      zip: 48149,
      city: 'Muenster',
      country: 'DE'
    },
    interests: [
      'Ionic', 'Angular', 'YouTube', 'Sports'
    ]
  };

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  openDetailsWithQueryParams() {
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        special: JSON.stringify(this.user)
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['details'], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

Here navigationExtras is the data that we are passing to details page.

details.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params && params.special) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(params.special);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

This way you can modify your code only for the data you want to transfer!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the [essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: There were 3 options in that link and you've chosen to copy the one that is described as *"option is more like an ugly hackish thing and not recommended"*?

Comment: Yes, I know. This was for the understanding purpose! I was not going for coding standard here...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass value from one page to another in Ionic 3. I will post some example code.

To pass data from one page to another,

```
this.navCtrl.push("Pagename",{keyname: value});
```

eg:

```
this.navCtrl.push("Startpage",{userdata:this.userdatapass});
```

To get data on the destination page,

```
variable_name = this.navParams.get('keyname');
```

eg:

```
this.userdataget = this.navParams.get('userdata')
```